# Функция с неопределенным количеством аргументов

Tags: c, функции

```
double equation_count(int count, double number, ...){
    double *p_number = &number, result = 0;
    int i;
    for(i=1; i <= count; i++){
        result+= pow(*p_number,i);
        p_number++;
    }

return result;
}
printf("%g",equation_count(2,2.0,3.0));
```

Функция должна возвращать сумму вещественных чисел в `i` cтепени.

В данном случае результат должен быть `11`, но возвращает `1`.
Проблема где-то с типом данных, т.к. с целыми числами функция работает.

Comment: Для работы с переменным числом аргументов всегда используйте [stdarg](https://linux.die.net/man/3/stdarg)

Comment: Вот откуда, интересно, ноги растут у этой манеры пытаться доступаться к переменнным аргументам как к некоему "массиву", через `double *p_number = &number;`. Часто вижу такое. Откуда это берется?

Comment: @AnT Кстати, да. Не встречал ни в какой литературе. Так что тоже очень интересно.

Comment: @Harry, ну пример приведен в книге "З. Я. Шпак  - Програмування мовою С", 229 стр. это книга на украинском. Автор книги читает нам лекции.

Comment: Скачал, полистал... книга 2006 года. Интересно, что форматы с плавающей точкой даны не со ссылкой на IEEE, а на Borland C :) Еще интересно, что возможность располагать объявления переменных где угодно, дана как отрицательная - мол, куда проще, если все переменные объявлены в одном месте (за 100 строк от использования :)). Просто `int` в книге - 2 байта (напоминаю, 2006 год), со ссылкой на Borland. Словом, я к тому, что вся книга основана на Borland C, причем не самой свежей версии. Ой, досмотрел до главы 14. Будете смеяться, но всерьез рассматриваются модели памяти для DOS, сегментная память,

Comment: прямой доступ к видеопамяти (с упоминанием монохромных адаптеров :) с их адресом B000:0000)... повеяло ностальгией :) Далее - тщательное изучение борландовского <conio.h>... Извините, конечно, я понимаю, что вы тут ни при чем... но, честное слово, для преподов можете сдавать по этой книге, но для себя - если планируете заниматься программированием - возьмите что-то поновее.

Comment: @Harry: Ну вот как раз таки рассмотрение моделей памяти можно было бы назвать полезным, хотя бы для того, чтобы студенты понимали, почему в языке существуют определенные концепции и ограничения. А то, избаловавшись плоской памятью, народные массы не врубаются в разницу между `size_t` и `unitptr_t`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что поступать надо *стандартно*.

```
double equation_count(int count, double number, ...)
{
    int i;
    double result = number;
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap,number);
    for(i=2; i <= count; i++)
    {
        result += pow(va_arg(ap,double),i);
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    printf("%g",equation_count(3,2.0,3.0,1.0));
}
```

Я бы даже сделал так, не вытаскивая `number` в список параметров:

```
double equation_count(int count, ...)
{
    int i;
    double result = 0;
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap,count);
    for(i = 1; i <= count; i++)
    {
        result += pow(va_arg(ap,double),i);
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return result;
}
```